# How to add Content-length To http request in php

Tags: php, httprequest, httpresponse

I want to use octoparse API.
AND I have error when I want to clear data in octoparse API.

AND this my code

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
$url = 'https://dataapi.octoparse.com/api/task/RemoveDataByTaskId?taskId=<mytaskid>';

$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'header'  => "Authorization: bearer <mykey>",
        'method'  => 'POST'
    )
);
$context  = stream_context_create($options);
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
if ($result === FALSE) { 
echo 'error';
}    

var_dump($result);
```

My result

```
Warning: file_get_contents(https://dataapi.octoparse.com/api/task/RemoveDataByTaskId?taskId=<mytaskid>): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 411 Length Required
```

And I try to add Content-length But It have an error My new code:

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
$url = 'https://dataapi.octoparse.com/api/task/RemoveDataByTaskId?taskId=<mytaskid>';

$a=strlen($url);
$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'header'  => "Authorization: bearer <my key>",
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'header'  => sprintf('Content-Length: %d', $a)
    )
);
$context  = stream_context_create($options);
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
if ($result === FALSE) { 
echo 'error';
}    

var_dump($result);
```

My result

```
Warning: file_get_contents(https://dataapi.octoparse.com/api/task/RemoveDataByTaskId?taskId=<mytaskid>): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!
```

Can anyone know how to solve my problem.
Thank.

Comment: remove `'header'  => "Authorization: bearer <my key>",` this line and check. i think it's work

Answer (score -1):

you are using multiple headers in HTTP. if you are using multiple headers then follow this process

```
'header' => array(
            "Authorization: bearer <my key>",
            sprintf('Content-Length: %d', $a)
        ),
```

And you can also used this code

```
$requestHeaders = array(
    'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Authorization: bearer <my key>',
    sprintf('Content-Length: %d', strlen($url));
);
$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'method' => 'POST',
        'header' => implode("\r\n", $requestHeaders),
    )
);
```

Comment: I try to use this code but I have an error again.
Warning: file_get_contents(https://dataapi.octoparse.com/api/task/RemoveDataByTaskId?taskId= <my taskid>): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!
I'm not sure how to measure content-Length.
Do you know how to measure content-Length In this API.